# How do I use Java 8 features in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I've installed JDK 8.  I set my JAVA_HOME to the JDK 8 directory.  I downloaded the latest Eclipse Luna.  I checked for updates.  I set my default (and only) Installed JRE to the JDK 8 directory.

I cannot set my project nor workspace compliance level to 1.8.  I even tried manually editing the preferences file to 1.8 to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?  Hopefully it's something simple.

PS  My project builds with java 8 fine.  I'm using gradle with source and target set to 1.8 and it builds and generates eclipse files, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luna will support Java 8 by default starting at Luna M7. For the time being you can install the Java 8 support patch for Kepler (either on Luna or Kepler).

Here is the update site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/

Comment: The link is a 404 now.

Comment: Java 8 is now available in Eclipse Luna: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php . For Kepler just look for Java8 in eclipse marketplace client or download java 8 capable edition of kepler: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-java8.php

Answer (score 0):

we can use most popular [jdk 8 features](http://beyondcorner.com/java-8-lambda-expression-features-tutorial-examples/) called "A lambda expression"
we can use this in the java IDE EE eclipse, usage is similar to the java program

Standard Syntax
Syntax:

(parameter-list) -> {body} 
Standard syntax of lambda expression contains three parts.

A list of parameter: It can be empty or non-empty as well.
Arrow-token: It is used to link parameter-list and body of expression.
body: It contains expressions and statements for lambda expressio