# for-each loops are not supported at this language level

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I'm new to programming and am on track to learning Java. I use the Intellij IDE for most of my programming. I was following along on a tutorial which made use for-each loops. on attempting to execute this in my IDE it gave me the following error

'for-each loops are not supported at this language level'

Here is the codeblock I am trying to execute

```
    public class test {
          public static void main(String args[]) {

          int omer[]={2,3,4,5,6,7};
          int total=0;

          for(int x:omer){
              System.out.println(x);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Change your IDE settings to use the Java 1.8 compiler

Comment: File Menu > Project Structure > Project, change Project Language Level to latest version I'm guessing. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22704620/5221346)

Comment: Foreach loop was added in java 1.5 so make sure that you are using atleas java 1.5 to compile and run your code.

Comment: @Gendarme That was pretty much it. Thank you for taking out time for telling  me that :)