# Why source is 1.6 if I'm using 1.8

Tags: java, spring, lambda, java-8

Like in the title, I'm trying to compile lambda, I'm using 1.8 jdk, and have no idea.

Error log here:
[image]

Proof that I really got 1.8:

part1:

[image]

part2:
[image]

Any ideas why I've got problem like this, lambda looks like this, but I'm sure its fine, because I'm doing code from a tutorial.

```
public Topic getTopic(final String id){
    topics.stream().filter(t -> t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
}
```

I was trying to find solution but really failed, thats why I'm writing here.
ps. sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703412/java-lambda-expressions-not-supported-at-this-language-level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a Java 8 JDK, but your project's language source level is still set to Java 6 (probably for compatibility). Therefore the JDK 8 `javac` is invoked in compatibility mode for Java 6 which causes it to reject your code because that uses Java 8 features. You probably want to fix the language level in your project's settings or `pom.xml`, and then recompile.

You can edit your `pom.xml` to fix this. See the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) for details on how to do this, but you likely want this:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```