# Why do I get error "Lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I'm using IntelliJ Idea and I get this error.

> Lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6

Got this when I updated from 2016 to the 2017 version of the community edition after I did something with gradle.

Settings: Java compiler: Project bytecode version: 1.8
Modules bytecode version: 1.8
Project SDK: 1.8
Project language level: default(8)
Modules 1.8 as well

Comment: You probably switched your java version to 1.6 by accident. Try updating java to 1.8 in order to have access to lambda function api's.

Comment: I only have java 8 installed, both SDK and JRE 8 version 144

Comment: Check your java version with `java -version` command. If by some reason you have 1.6 version then uninstall it or set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to `jre_1.8.X/bin` directory.

Comment: Check your IDE settings, you may have it (or gradle) to Java 1.6

Comment: [This answer/suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45361596/7598776) might help

Comment: You can't expect to use Java 1.8 features with `-source 1.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Settings -> Compiler - > Java Compiler`. 
If that doesn't work,
for **MAVEN:** you can set it in your pom.xml, like this:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

for gradle :

```
sourceCompatibility = "1.8"; 
targetCompatibility = "1.8"; // defaults to sourceCompatibility
```

Answer (score 1):

that because in you IDEA the *Project language level* set to **"6 - @Override in interface"**

to solve goto:

```
File -> Other Setting -> Default Project Structure
```

now change **Project language level** to `Lambdas , type annotation etc.` and then click **OK**