# save Image As Png with bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera

Hi  I use this Library in my app  for take picture  [Camera2](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/CameraRecorder-android) I set the camera in my app but I have a problem with this part of code

```
captureBitmap(bitmap -> {
                    new Handler().post(() -> {
                        String imagePath = getImageFilePath();
                        saveAsPngImage(bitmap, imagePath);
                        exportPngToGallery(getApplicationContext(), imagePath);
                    });
                });`
```

When I paste it on my code it says me this

> Lambda expressions are not supported at language level '1.7

So I change my java Language for 1.8 but after I did this my build failed with this error

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

And now I'm stuck with this . So if anyone know who can I use the captureimage void without uptade my Language it would be great thanks

Comment: have you tried these?

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703412/java-lambda-expressions-not-supported-at-this-language-level

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1

Comment: Yes already but I just want use this void

Comment: Although it sounds weird, could you try it again after each step:
1. Free up some RAM by closing programs
2. Closing Android Studio and reboot your PC/laptop.