# Android Studio doesn't show suggestion for lambda expression

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added Java 8 compileOptions in app module

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

I also have checked "Anonymous type can be replaced with lambda" in Inspections/Java8 in Preferences

However the suggestion is never shown in Android Studio.

I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this Help ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703412/java-lambda-expressions-not-supported-at-this-language-level

Comment: Due to a plugin I installed, the waring has been disabled. Problem solved.